# How do I crush my melons?

Tags: bag-it

In the section of levels where you get to mindlessly destroy all of your groceries, a few levels have ribbons relating to destroying a certain number of melons.

How do I destroy them? I have piled things on them and dropped them on top of one another from crazy heights but my melons just won't break.

How do I destroy my melons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dropping it from the very top of the bag. When it lands, it should break.